# Tem como passar métodos como parâmetro?

Tags: java, método, parâmetros, java-8

Em Java, posso passar métodos como parâmetros?

Exemplo:

```
public class Teste {
    public String metodoA(){
        //faz alguma coisa
    }

    public void metodoB(double numero){
        //faz alguma coisa
    }

    public void metodoC(Metodo metodo, double numero){
        metodo(numero);
    }

    public void metodoD(Metodo metodo){
        metodo();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Teste teste = new Teste();
        teste.metodoC(metodoA, 10.2);
        teste.metodoD(metodoB);
    }
}
```

Outro exemplo:

```
public double getRuntime(int[] vetor, Metodo metodo){
    this.initialTime = System.nanoTime();
    metodo(vetor);
    double tempo = System.nanoTime() - initialTime;
    return tempo;
}
```

Chamando o método seria assim:

```
getRuntime(vetor[], BubbleSort.bubbleSort());
```

A execução seria assim(Variando o método a ser chamado que no caso foi bubbleSort()):

```
public double getRuntime(int[] vetor, Metodo metodo){
    this.initialTime = System.nanoTime();
    BubbleSort.bubbleSort(vetor);
    double tempo = System.nanoTime() - initialTime;
    return tempo;
}
```

Continua confuso e pelo que fiquei sabendo o java não permite passagem de métodos como parâmetros. Mas quais seriam as alternativas para se conseguir este objetivo?

Comment: Passar o retorno do metodo como paramtro, sim, agora usar um metodo como se fosse um objeto, creio que não.

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o que pretende fazer. No método `main()` o que são `metodoA` e `metodoB`? São métodos do objecto `teste`?

Comment: Sim, metodoA e metodoB são métodos do objeto teste.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## TL;DR

Existem várias formas de parametrizar métodos em Java:

- A de mais baixo nível por reflexão;
- A tradicional usando uma interface específica;
- Diretamente na forma mais moderna introduzida no Java 8

## Exemplos

Dada a classe abaixo:

```
class Sorting {
    public static void staticSort(String[] vetor) {
        Arrays.sort(vetor);
    }
    public void sort(String[] vetor) {
        Arrays.sort(vetor);
    }
}
```

E o seguinte vetor de `String`:

```
String[] vetor = { "Maria", "José" };
```

### Reflexão

Podemos usar o tipo [`Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) para receber a referência do método, assim:

```
public static long executar(Method metodo, String[] vetor) {
    long initialTime = System.nanoTime();
    try {
        metodo.invoke(null, new Object[] { vetor });
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return System.nanoTime() - initialTime;
}
```

O método `invoke` da instância de um método permite chamar o método referenciado. O primeiro parâmetro é a instância do objeto, mas se o método for estático basta passar `null` e depois um array com os parâmetros, que no caso é um array de `String`.

Obtermos a referência ao método assim:

```
Method metodo = Sorting.class.getDeclaredMethod("staticSort", String[].class);
```

E a chamada ao método fica assim:

```
executar(metodo, vetor);
```

Os problemas da reflexão incluem:

- Ela pode levar a erros em tempo de execução que não são pegos em tempo de compilação, pois os nomes dos métodos são recuperados usando simples `String`s.
- Desempenho. Usar reflexão é muito mais lento.
- Código verboso e "feio", tendo que tratar várias exceções complicadas.

### Usando interfaces

Uma forma indireta de passar um método é usar interfaces específicas para o determinado uso.

O exemplo mais comum disso são threads que implementam a interface [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). Aliás, esta interface pode e é usada em diferentes aplicações que precisam passar um método a ser executado que não recebe nem retorna valor.

De qualquer forma, você pode criar sua própria interface. Exemplo:

```
interface Sorter {
    void sort(String[] vetor);
}
```

E então pode criar quantas implementações quiser. Exemplo:

```
class BubbleSorter implements Sorter {
    @Override
    public void sort(String[] vetor) { ... } 
}
```

E o método consumidor será:

```
void executar(Sorter sorter, String[] vetor) { ... }
```

Então o método principal será algo assim:

```
Sorter bubbleSorter = new BubbleSorter();
executar(bubbleSorter, vetor);
```

A vantagem dessa abordagem é que ela é eficiente, torna o código fácil de entender e também estender com novos tipos de implementações.

A desvantagem é que exige a criação de novas interfaces para cada tipo de método que você quer parametrizar.

Esta é uma abordagem razoavelmente flexível, pois permite que qualquer objeto possa implementar essa interface, mas não tão flexível, pois você só pode ter um método `sort` por classe e tem que ter a mesma assinatura.

### Referências de Métodos do Java 8

**Não é só de lâmbdas que o Java 8 ganhou fama**. Esta versão também introduziu [referências a métodos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Existem três formas principais de representar semanticamente as referências de métodos, usando as seguintes interfaces:

- [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html): um método consumidor que recebe um parâmetro e não retorna nada.
- [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html): um fornecedor que não recebe parâmetros e retorna um valor.
- [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html): uma função que recebe um parâmetro e retorna um valor.

Existem outros tipos de [interfaces funcionais](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) mais especializadas, mas estas são as mais genéricas.

Um método de execução genérico poderia então ser escrito assim:

```
public static long executar(Consumer<String[]> metodo, String[] vetor) {
    long initialTime = System.nanoTime();
    metodo.accept(vetor);
    return System.nanoTime() - initialTime;
}
```

Usamos a interface `Consumer`, já que nosso método apenas recebe um vetor de `String` e não retorna nada.

A chamada ao nosso método de execução usando o método de ordenação estático descrito mais acima ficaria assim:

```
executar(Sorting::staticSort, vetor);
```

Se quisermos fazer referência a um método de instância, basta usar o nome da instância antes do operador `::`, assim:

```
Sorting instancia = new Sorting();
executar(instancia::sort, vetor);
```

Esta abordagem é mais flexível e superior semanticamente do que as edições anteriores.

Note que qualquer método que seja compatível com a interface usada como parâmetro pode ser passado como referência. Não precisa ser necessariamente as 3 interfaces que mencionei assim. Por exemplo, se você usar a interface `Comparator` como parâmetro, pode passar como referência qualquer método que recebe dois parâmetros do mesmo tipo. Você pode usar suas próprias interfaces também.

A limitação aqui fica na quantidade de parâmetros. Se você quiser passar vários valores, vai precisar ter uma interface com a quantidade certa de parâmetros com os mesmos tipos. No entanto, esta limitação é essencial para que o programa seja compilado com segurança, caso contrário vários erros iriam passar despercebidos até o momento de execução.

## Considerações

Nos exemplos acima, usei um vetor de `String` como tipo. Isso pode parecer limitador. Entretanto, lembre-se de que você pode usar genéricos para criar interfaces funcionais que "obrigam" o código cliente a passar um método que seja uma função, consumidor ou fornecedor respeitando as regras de tipos impostas por você.

Finalmente, se quiser imprimir o vetor e conferir o resultado, pode usar isso:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(vetor).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

Answer (score 5):

De uma maneira geral, de forma direta, não.

É possível criar uma classe, que pode ser até anônima, que contenha esse método e aí chamar o método desta classe segundo alguma convenção adotada. Também é possível uma classe implementar uma interface com do método que precisa ser passado e sua implementação ser realizada no momento da instanciação da classe.

Isto era muito adotado até o Java 7 e ainda é por alguns programadores que não gostam do estilo um pouco mais funcional que Java está seguindo agora.

Em Java 8 as [*lambdas*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) foram introduzidas e é uma forma de passar um código como parâmetro, que é uma simplificação do processo, embora não seja exatamente o que deseja.

Não vou me arriscar por um exemplo porque nunca usei isto em Java. Tem uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2186993/221800) que dá um bom exemplo. No *link* anterior também tem várias formas de atingir este objetivo.

Tem outras opções, como reflexão, mas acho que estas são melhores.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Não será bem o que pretende mas julgo que será o mais perto que se possa conseguir(sem usar *reflection*).

Defina uma interface:

```
public interface Action<T>
{
    void execute(T valor);
}
```

Por cada método que queira executar em `getRuntime()` crie uma classe que implemente essa interface.
Por exemplo:

```
public class BubbleSortAction implements Action<int[]>{

    public void execute(int[] valor){
        BubbleSort.bubbleSort(valor);
    }
}
```

Declare o método `getRuntime()` desta forma:

```
public <T> double getRuntime(T valor, Action<T> metodo){
    this.initialTime = System.nanoTime();
    metodo.execute(valor);
    double tempo = System.nanoTime() - initialTime;
    return tempo;
}
```

Chame-o assim:

```
int[] vetor = {1,2,3,4};
BubbleSortAction bubbleSortAction = new BubbleSortAction();
getRuntime(vetor, bubbleSortAction);
```

---

Usando *Reflection* seria qualquer coisa assim(não testei)

```
public double getRunTime(Class<?> classe, String metodo, Object... parametros) 
        throws  NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?>[] parametrosClasse = new Class[parametros.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < parametros.length; i++){
        parametrosClasse[i] = parametros[i].getClass();
    }
    Method m = classe.getClass().getMethod(metodo, parametrosClasse);
    long initialTime = System.nanoTime();
    Object ret = m.invoke(classe, parametros);
    double tempo = System.nanoTime() - initialTime;
    return tempo;
}
```

Para usar:

```
    int[] vetor = {1,2,3,4};
    try {
        getRunTime(BubbleSort.class, "bubbleSort", vetor);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Notas:

- Terá de ter cuidado em não se enganar na ordem e tipo de parâmetros passados.
- Não se enganar no nome do método.
- O tempo que demora a executar um método via *reflection*, à partida, é maior do que quando chamado normalmente.