# Invocar um método por reflexão

Tags: java, reflexão

Eu dei uma olhada nessa pergunta [Tem como passar métodos como parâmetro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109898/tem-como-passar-m%C3%A9todos-como-par%C3%A2metro) e tentei invocar um método de uma classe, em outra, passando como parâmetros a tela/class e o nome do método.

A finalidade de fazer isso, é que na minha aplicação, eu faço várias rotinas dentro de um determinado método, que é disparado por um evento (um `ActionListener`, por exemplo) e toda vez que preciso fazer algo "diferente", eu tenho que sobrescrever o evento que dispara esse método, colocar a nova rotina e às vezes até repetir outras.

Eu acredito que fazendo desta maneira, eu poderia ter uma possibilidade maior em fazer algumas rotinas. Eu poderia ter várias telas diferentes com o componente `MyField` que faz uma mesma função, e nas telas que eu quiser que um determinado método seja executado junto ou apos os métodos do `MyField`, eu faria tranquilamente, passando ele como parâmetro.

Aparentemente, me pareceu uma ideia coerente, porém, posso estar enganado, e neste caso, estou aberto a sugestões mais eficientes e "corretas".

Para ilustrar melhor o que eu pretendo, fiz um exemplo simples.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TesteReflection extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable startApp = () -> {
            TesteReflection tr = new TesteReflection();
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(startApp);
    }

    private MyField myField = new MyField();
    private JButton button = new JButton("Click !");

    public TesteReflection() {
        add(button);
        setSize(300, 200);
        setVisible(true);
        button();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void button() {
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            metodoA();
        });
    }

    private void metodoA() {
        MyField.actions(myField, TesteReflection.class, "metodoB");
    }

    private void metodoB() {
        System.out.println("Método B");
        //faz alguma coisa ..
    }
}
```

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MyField extends JPanel {

    private JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();

    public MyField() {
        actions();
    }

    private void actions() {
        jTextField.addActionListener(e -> {
            //faz alguma coisa ..
        });
    }

    public static void actions(MyField component, Class tela, String methodName) {
        component.getjTextField().addActionListener(e -> {
            try {
                //Method method = tela.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, new Class[]{});
                Method method = tela.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, String.class);
                method.setAccessible(true);
                method.invoke(tela);

                System.out.println("Chamei com sucesso o método " + methodName);
            } catch (Exception ev) {
                ev.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public JTextField getjTextField() {
        return jTextField;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu reflection falha porque o `metodoB` é um método de instância e não um método estático. Assim sendo, para invocá-lo (seja normalmente ou por reflection), você precisa da instância.

Você até tenta resolver isso usando `tela.getClass()`. Porém, `tela` é do tipo `Class`, e portanto o resultado disso seria `Class.class`, que definitivamente não é o que você quer. Além disso, ao especificar `String.class` como parâmetro, você não vai encontrar o que queria, pois o método que você quer é apenas `metodoB()` e não `metodoB(String)`.

O código pode ser assim:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TesteReflection extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new TesteReflection();
        });
    }

    private MyField myField = new MyField();
    private JButton button = new JButton("Click !");

    public TesteReflection() {
        add(button);
        setSize(300, 200);
        setVisible(true);
        button();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void button() {
        button.addActionListener(e -> metodoA());
    }

    private void metodoA() {
        myField.actions(this, TesteReflection.class, "metodoB");
    }

    private void metodoB() {
        System.out.println("Método B");
        //faz alguma coisa ..
    }
}
```

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MyField extends JPanel {

    private JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();

    public MyField() {
    }

    public <E> void actions(E tela, Class<E> classe, String methodName) {
        jTextField.addActionListener(e -> {
            try {
                Method method = classe.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
                method.setAccessible(true);
                method.invoke(tela);

                System.out.println("Chamei com sucesso o método " + methodName);
            } catch (Exception ev) {
                ev.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Entretanto, isso que você quer provavelmente ficaria melhor e mais fácil com *method references*:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TesteReflection extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new TesteReflection();
        });
    }

    private MyField myField = new MyField();
    private JButton button = new JButton("Click !");

    public TesteReflection() {
        add(button);
        setSize(300, 200);
        setVisible(true);
        button();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void button() {
        button.addActionListener(e -> metodoA());
    }

    private void metodoA() {
        myField.actions(this::metodoB);
    }

    private void metodoB() {
        System.out.println("Método B");
        //faz alguma coisa ..
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MyField extends JPanel {

    private JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();

    public MyField() {
    }

    public void actions(Runnable r) {
        jTextField.addActionListener(e -> r.run());
    }
}
```

Comment: O que o :: faz ? É algum tipo de "teste" ?

Comment: @GustavoSantos É o *method reference* (referência a método). No caso o `this::metodoB` significa "*o método `metodoB` do objeto `this`*". O compilador se esforça em tentar descobrir qual interface funcional (uma interface que só tem um único método abstrato) é compatível com a referência e com o contexto no qual ela é usada. Nesse caso, ela é compatível com `Runnable`, pois o retorno é `void`, o `metodoB` não recebe parâmetros e ele está sendo usado como parâmetro a uma chamada onde o tipo é `Runnable`. [continua...]

Comment: [...continuação] Com isso, é mais ou menos como se o compilador substituisse `this::metodoB` por `new Runnable() { public void run() { metodoB(); }}`.

Comment: compreendi ! E não querendo abusar da sua ajuda, mais, o que acontece quando o método tem parâmetros, ou algum tipo de retorno ?

Comment: @GustavoSantos O compilador olha quais interfaces funcionais podem ser usadas no contexto e quais são os possíveis métodos a que o programa se refere (como podem ser sobrecarregados, pode haver mais do que um). Então ele verifica qual dos possíveis métodos é compatível com qual possível interface funcional e dá erro se houver mais do que uma possibilidade ou se não houver nenhuma. Lembre-se que o método da interface funcional pode ter diferentes retornos, diferentes tipos de parâmetros e diferentes exceções declaradas, tudo isso é levado em conta para verificar se é compatível ou não.

Comment: quando um método tem parâmetros, eu não consigo usar method reference, ou mesmo reflection. Como seria possível fazer isso ? O java tem um método, implementação ou qualquer outra coisa, que me permita invocar um método com parâmetros ?

Comment: @GustavoSantos Sim, você consegue em ambos os casos, tanto com method references quanto com reflection. Vamos supor que `metodoB` tivesse um parâmetro do tipo `JLabel` e retornasse uma `String`. Nesse caso, se o método `actions` recebesse `Function<JLabel, String>`, o compilador veria que essa seria a interface funcional compatível. No caso do reflection, você usaria `classe.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, JLabel.class);` e `method.invoke(tela, algumaJLabel);`. A chamada ao `invoke` retorna `Object`, no caso o que for retornado pelo método invocado por reflection.

Comment: Function espera dois valores, correto ? Porém, se o método for void e passar apenas parâmetro, o que é usado ?

Comment: @GustavoSantos Não. `Function<A, B>` tem um parâmetro do tipo `A` e um retorno do tipo `B`. No caso de `void` com um parâmetro `X`, use `Consumer<X>`. Dê uma olhada nas interfaces do pacote `java.util.function` que lá é que a maioria delas estão definidas (com exceção de `Runnable`). Se você estiver em um caso onde nenhuma das interfaces funcionais existentes servir, invente a sua: basta declarar uma interface com um único método abstrato e se o seu método tiver um formato compatível com ela, o compilador aceita o *method reference*.

Comment: Muito bom, vou dar uma lida com certeza. Obrigado !